# How to insert characters within file names to make them the same length?

Tags: python

I'm trying to align terminal output to make visually parsing errors easier. [I asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124885/how-do-i-add-line-padding-to-my-terminal-output/72125424?noredirect=1#comment127443171_72125424) which is now answered and closed. I believe the issue I have is to do with how I'm generating the terminal statements.

To address this I'm attempting to change standardised the length of the file names instead of the terminal output.

This is what I'm dealing with:

```
Search Count: 79 - Searching for: The Flying Brick.png ---------------- 004 keypoints matched - 481
Search Count: 80 - Searching for: The Loud One.png ---------------- 001 keypoints matched - 478
Search Count: 81 - Searching for: theTobyKiDD.png ---------------- 001 keypoints matched - 474
Search Count: 82 - Searching for: Thoraner.png ---------------- 000 keypoints matched - 441
Search Count: 83 - Searching for: TiMe2BuRn.png ---------------- 002 keypoints matched - 479
Search Count: 84 - Searching for: Ty Pod Challenge (3).png ---------------- 010 keypoints matched - 416
```

This is what I want:

```
Search Count: 79 - Searching for: The Flying Brick.png ------------ 004 keypoints matched - 481
Search Count: 80 - Searching for: The Loud One.png ---------------- 001 keypoints matched - 478
Search Count: 81 - Searching for: theTobyKiDD.png ----------------- 001 keypoints matched - 474
Search Count: 82 - Searching for: Thoraner.png -------------------- 000 keypoints matched - 441
Search Count: 83 - Searching for: TiMe2BuRn.png ------------------- 002 keypoints matched - 479
Search Count: 84 - Searching for: Ty Pod Challenge (3).png -------- 010 keypoints matched - 416
```

The test cases in the answered question all work, but I can't seem to get it work in my actual code. I'm trying a different approach.

```
import glob

pad_images = glob.glob(r"C:\test\*.png")
split_images = []

for i in pad_images:
    split = i.split("\\")[-1]
    split_images.append(split)

longest_file_name = max(split_images, key=len) 
longest = longest_file_name.split("\\")[-1] 
longest_int = len(longest)

for f in split_images:
    parts = f.split('.')
    new_part1 = '_' * (24-len(parts[0])) + parts[0]
    new_part = '.'.join([parts[0], new_part1])
    print(new_part)
```

I'm getting:

```
`010000111._______________010000111`
```

I want:

```
`010000111_______________.png`
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific questioon, `parts[1]` should be `png`, unless I misunderstood.

More generally, I recommend getting familiar with:

- [string methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) like `str.zfill()` and `str.rjust()`
- `str.format()` or f-strings (achieves something similar), and
- To get the most out of `format`, the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

For example, let's look at your example. It's a tiny bit awkard to put a space in after the string and before the fill, but this:

```
fname, ext = 'The Flying Brick', 'png'
print(fname.ljust(32, '_') + '.' + ext)
```

results in `The Flying Brick________________.png`, or you can achieve something similar with an f-string:

```
print(f'{fname:_<32}.{ext}')
```

Comment: That's sort of the direction the link/other question was taking me but I was struggling because I'm loading and generating the output in different functions and I think it's a bit beyond where I'm at skill level wise to piece together. Basically the outputs are the print values from a loop, and I everything I was seeing on f.strings (and similar) would only address it if I was loading everything at once. Which will require a significant code re-write I think.

Comment: I tried to make the examples more relevant to your task.

Comment: `s = (f.ljust(10, "_"))` is adding the padding after .png The Flying Brick.png_____ etc how can I move it to the flying brick______.png instead? That would work

Comment: Same with `(foo + " ").ljust(10, '-')` it appends after the .png, I'm trying to add it before, sorry if that wasn't clear in the OP but that's why I'm trying to use split.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused -- the first part of your question wants a bunch of hyphens after filenames, but the second half wants underscores inside the filename. Maybe you can edit your question to be a bit clearer about the actual problem you're trying to solve? (Sounds like it's the second one?) In the meantime, I edited it again.

Comment: Accepted the answer and posted my own below. The initial post is only overly relevant if you check the link. The second was indeed correct! I updated my intended outcome at the bottom of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob

pad_images = glob.glob(r"C:\test\*.png")
split_images = []

for i in pad_images:
    split = i.split("\\")[-1]
    split_images.append(split)

longest_file_name = max(split_images, key=len) 
longest = longest_file_name.split("\\")[-1] 
longest_int = len(longest)

for i in split_images:
    parts = i.split('.')
    new = (parts[0]).ljust(longest_int, '_') + "." + parts[1]
    print(new)
```

Some examples from the folder in question:

```
Atomic Samurai__________.png
BabyYodatheBased________.png
Baradum_________________.png
bcav____________________.png
Beltze__________________.png
BeltzeBubi______________.png
ChihuahuaPaws___________.png
Cptn Cnnbz______________.png
```